# In what way does quoting parameters to `find` matter?

Tags: command-line, find, quoting, wildcards

When looking for txt files, I run this command:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print
```

This gives me a list of all the text files beneath current directory.

However, `find . -name *.txt -print` gives me the following error:
`find: paths must precede expression: mein.txt`

Is this the generally expected behavior? What difference do
the quotation marks make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a token that is not quoted, it is your shell that will perform
expansion, not the command that you are running.

This means that, when you enter `find . -name "*.txt" -print`, then
find receives the literal `*.txt` as one of its parameters, and uses
this pattern as the argument to its `-name` option, which will match
the names of files found against it before applying `-print`.

On the other hand, when you enter `find . -name *.txt -print`, the
shell passes the expanded version of `*.txt` to find. Several cases
are possible:

1. There are no files matching `*.txt` in the current directory: find
   receives a literal `*.txt` (assuming default bash settings);
2. there is exactly one file matching `*.txt` in the current
   directory; let's say it is `a.txt`: find receives this file name,
   and matches all files named `a.txt` found starting at the current
   directory;
3. several files match `*.txt` in the current directory (this appears
   to be your case): `-name` receives the first one as its parameter,
   and the others are further path parameters to find, which complains
   about not being given all paths before the expression.

This is the expected behavior.

---

Let's assume the following file hierarchy:

```
.
├── a.txt
├── b.txt
├── c.txt
└── foo
    ├── a.txt
    ├── b.txt
    └── c.txt
```

The actual parameters that find receives in eah case can be observed
by replacing the call to find with `printf '%s\n'`, which will print
each expanded argument on its own line:

```
$ printf '%s\n' . -name "*.txt" -print
.
-name
*.txt
-print

$ printf '%s\n' . -name *.txt -print
.
-name
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
-print
```

As you can see, the second invokation that you posted is equivalent,
given the existing files, to `find . -name a.txt b.txt c.txt -print`.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior - it's is known as "shell globbing". Without the quotation marks, the `*.txt` is expanded by the shell to pass the entire list of files that match that expression to the `find` command. By surrounding it in quotes, you tell the shell to pass the literal string `*.txt` to `find`. You can achieve the same protection by using other escaping methods, such as `find . -name \*.txt` or `find . -name '*.txt'`.

Comment: Now I understand the difference. Thank you for your good explanation of this topic! Appreciate that.